# How to check the polarity of a common-mode choke?

Tags: inductor, pinout, common-mode-choke

I purchased some common-mode chokes and the documentation provided states:

[image: Choke pinout]

As this pinout does not correspond to other chokes of the same format, I have doubts about the position of the dots (pins 1 and 3).

So I tried to measure the values of the inductors with an L-meter.

[image]

With the assembly on the left I obtain a low value: 100 µH. It would therefore be the differential mode.

With the right assembly I obtain a high value: 40 mH. This would therefore be the common mode.

This leads me to think that the dots should be at 1 and 4 and not at 1 and 3 as shown in the schematic. Is my reasoning valid?

Comment: The chance for such a blatant error in a datasheet is somewhat higher for a dodgy manufacturer (or datasheet author gemerally). Where is it from?

Comment: Dodgy manufacturer? can't find datasheet.
But dodgy vendor: AliExpress...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *This leads me to think that the dots should be at 1 and 4 and not at 1
> and 3 as shown in the schematic. Is my reasoning valid?*

Yes, your reasoning is valid.

You can also prove this using a signal generator and an oscilloscope. If the non-dotted pins (2 and 4) are grounded and a sinewave is applied to pin 1, you'd expect pin 3's output voltage to be in phase if the marking is correct.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if the dots are well placed and the non dotted pins are grounded: by injecting a signal on one of the dot, I must find a signal in phase on the other dot?

Comment: @Nikita correct.